# docker run rocketeq error

Tags: java, docker

My OS is win10 and use docker toolbox running contain.When I run a rocketmq image ,it always restarting the log show the error is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/rocketmq/conf/broker.properties (Is a directory)
```

My dockerfile part is

```
CMD cd /opt/rocketmq/bin && export JAVA_OPT=" 
-Duser.home=/opt" && sh mqbroker -c /opt/rocketmq/conf/broker.properties
VOLUME /opt/logs /opt/store
```

And docker compose.yml part is

```
volumes:
        - "/e/code/rocketmq-externals/rocketmq-docker/4.1.0-incubating/conf/broker-a/logs:/opt/logs"
        - "/e/code/rocketmq-externals/rocketmq-docker/4.1.0-incubating/conf/broker-a/store:/opt/store"
        - "/e/code/rocketmq-externals/rocketmq-docker/4.1.0-incubating/conf/broker-a/conf/broker.properties:/opt/rocketmq/conf/broker.properties"
```

I think somewrong is the volum map relation

Thanks!

Comment: Do `cat /opt/rocketmq/conf/broker.properties` and add the output to your question.

Comment: the error is fileNotFound , I think is nothing wrong with properties content

Comment: Your error itself says it's a directory, not a file. That's why I asked to confirm if it is a file indeed.